# What is causing this post-commit error "database is locked" when I perform SVN commits?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, svn

I have a Ubuntu machine acting as a subversion server via an svnserve daemon (as root) in my private network.  The svnserve daemon reads from a mounted SMB share that is on our raid setup.  I can access the server from my various SVN clients just fine.  I can also commit changes without problem, except that after each commit, I get the following error:

> post-commit FS processing had error 'database is locked'.

Commits succeed, so I can use the system, but this error is annoying and troubling.  I've tried seaching for a solution and not had much luck.

Is anyone able to help me fix this error?

Comment: (1) Are you using the same subversion version on both server & client? (2) Are server & client very far geographically? (3) Is it possible that another long commit is in progress?

Comment: Does running `svn cleanup` help?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `nobrl` mount option might help. This disables byte-range locks.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1056511)

Comment: @Burgi why does this not answer the question? I had the same problem and it helped.

Comment: @vision - You indicated adding the option **might help**, which sounds like you are submitting a comment/suggest, instead of answering the author's question.

Comment: Adding "nobrl" performs the following on SMB/CIFS mounts :
Do not send byte range lock requests to the server. This is necessary for certain applications that break with cifs style mandatory byte range locks (and most cifs servers do not yet support requesting advisory byte range locks).